# google chrome & other: saving xml+xsl as html

Tags: html, xslt

Page of the site, built on a client-side xml + xsl technologies, some browsers like Firefox, Google Chrome, etc.. save the file as pure xml. Without the xsl and css. As a result, saved the page looks horrible. Is it possible to force the save page as html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firefox's save dialog (6.0.2), you can see that one of the options is `Web Page, Complete`. This means that just like normal XML, it also finds all the other linked documents (like CSS files for example) and saves them in the appropriate directory for offline browsing.

If your browser has this feature, then you can see it in its save dialog. Otherwise, it simply doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome: open F12 to bring up developer tools. Go to `Elements` tab and right click on html-element and select `Copy../Copy element` in context menu. Paste into you text editor of choice and save it as an html page.